# get all notifications sent to a user

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM FirebaseMessaging to send push notifications to user of my app.

Is there a way to get all notifications sent to one single user or I have to store them in Firestore db?

Comment: You have to store them in the db

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "get all notifications sent to one single user".  But if you're trying to get a history of all messages previously sent to a user via the FCM API, that's not possible.  FCM doesn't remember anything about messages previously sent.  You have to keep that record yourself, if that's what you need.

Comment: i want like notification in facebook i can see all previous notifs

Comment: You can store the data to Cloud Firestore and call them in a Listview in flutter. You can also set a click handler with a unique key to get the data that your notifications has been seen or not.